# Showing Google Maps Marker infoname on Mouseover of a Dynamically Generated DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I want to introduce a **functionality which allows a marker's infoname to appear or disappear upon mouseover or mouseout of a corresponding DIV element** generated from jQuery. However, I am getting a "**a is undefined**" error on line 19 of [main.js](http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_gb/mapfiles/api-3/5/15/main.js). After extensive testing on my script, I realise that this has something to do with the marker in the newly added lines as commented below:

```
function addMarker(A) {
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(A.lat, A.lng);      
 var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/r.png',
  new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 30));
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: point,
  icon: image,
 });
}

function addInfoName(A) {
 var infoname = new infoName; // custom object
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {infoname.show();});
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(event) {infoname.hide();});
 infoname.open(map, marker);
}

function showResult(A) {
 $('#results').append('<DIV id=' + A.pid + '>{Blah Blah Blah}</DIV>');
 return document.getElementById(A.pid);
}

function process(json) {
 $('#results').empty();
 total = json.details.length;
 for(i=0; i<total; i++) {
  var detail = json.details[i];
  var marker;
  addMarker(detail);
  addInfoName(detail);

// these new lines are added
  var listDisplay = showResult(detail);
  listDisplay.onmouseover = function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover');};
  listDisplay.onmouseout = function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseout');};
 }
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {$.getJSON(query, process);});
```

The error disappears if I merge the function `addInfoName` into `process`. However, all the DIVs will point to the last marker if I do so. My question is, **how do I modify my script to achieve the functionality mentioned above**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you've got a variable `marker` declared local to the `process` function, but you're trying to read and write to it from other functions. In particular, `addMarker` writes to `marker` without `var`, which causes an accidental global variable to be created. Meanwhile `process` is not actually writing to the `marker` local it has declared, so it contains `undefined`, which will trip the Google Maps code up when you pass that in.

(Tools like jslint, or ECMAScript 5 Strict Mode can catch accidental globals for you. Note `total` and `i` are also accidental globals.)

It looks like `addMarker` and `addInfoname` have been hacked out of the body of `process` without tying up the variables from `process` that both of them used. If they were included in the body of `process` it would work, but you'd get the described behaviour where the same `marker` value was used for every div because of the Closure Loop Problem.

This problem occurs in languages with closures and function-level scope, which includes JavaScript, Python and others. In these languages any variables defined by or inside a `for` loop are local to the containing function, *not* reallocated every time you go around the loop. So if you make a closure referring to `i` in the first iteration of the loop, it's the same variable `i` as you refer to in the second iteration of the loop; every instance of the function has a closure over the same variable `i` so every function will see the same value. The same would be true of `marker`.

The Closure Loop Problem can be avoided through use of a second closure that keeps the loop variable in an argument, or, more cleanly, using a closure-based loop mechanism instead of the C-like `for` loop. ECMAScript 5 offers `array.forEach()` for this purpose and jQuery offers `$.each()`:

```
function process(json) {
    $('#results').empty();
    var gev= google.maps.event;
    $.each(json.details, function(detaili, detail) {
        var marker= addMarker(detail.lat, detail.lng);

        $('#results').append($('<div>', {
            text: detail.name,
            mouseover: function() { gev.trigger(marker, 'mouseover'); },
            mouseout: function() { gev.trigger(marker, 'mouseout'); }
        }));

        var infoname= new InfoName();
        gev.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { infoname.show(); });
        gev.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() { infoname.hide(); });
        infoname.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function addMarker(lat, lng) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            'images/r.png',
            new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 30)
        )
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it generated a "pixOffset is null" error from my custom script for the infoName object. Is it possible to keep the `addInfoName` function outside? Thanks for your detailed explanation on the Closure Loop Problem, it really helped me a lot.

Comment: You can kick the four lines out into a separate function if you like, but you'll have to pass `marker` into it as an argument. It won't make any difference to `pixOffset` being null which you'll have to chase up in that other script.

Comment: @ bobince, I found I am missing a `new` after `position:` in the `addMarker` function which causes the `pixOffset is null` problem. Your method works. Now what is left for me is to figure out how to put the `id` and `blah blah blah` into append. Thank you very much for your time and effort :)

Comment: Use the attributes in the `<div>` construction call to set those (see `text: detail.name` above). Do you need to set an ID though? You'll already have a reference to the div; there is no need to set an ID just to re-fetch the same reference using `$('#id')`.

Comment: I found another way [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627202/appending-html-content-with-attributes-to-a-jquery-selector). Yes, you are right that there is no need to set an ID any more.

Answer (score 1):

The "a is undefined" error is probably because you are trying to create the map before the dom is ready.  At least, that's the only time I have seen it.  I can't tell from your code where you're creating it, but make sure that the map div is ready. You either have to place the call to your initialize function at the bottom of the page or in an page load listener. Here's one way you can do that (this can go anywhere in the page):

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
        $.getJSON(query, process);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Also notice that your idle listener goes in that init function, too, since it won't be able to run until the map has been created.

If that's not causing the "a is undefined" error, then I can't see it in the code you've posted.  I do, however, see some other problems with your code.  So maybe that is actually what's causing it.  First, the `var marker;` definition in `process` doesn't do anything.  Here you are creating a local variable, but that local variable never gets defined.  Then `addMarker` you are creating a global variable by defining `marker` without the `var`. So the marker in `addInfoname` always refers to the global marker, which will always be the last marker defined.  So that's why the divs are always showing up with the last marker.  I would put a return before `marker = ...` in addMarker, and use it to set the marker variable like this:

```
var marker = addMarker(detail);
```

In `process`, of course.  Then you also have to send this to addInfoname as a parameter so it gets the correct one.

Comment: Hi 150PoundsOfDonamite, it doesn't work. The same `a is undefined` error appears.

Comment: I took your second suggestion with `var map` being declared outside the function `initialize()` so that it could be used by the function `addMarker`. However, it still shows the same error. I have seen people using jQuery without the `initialize()` function, so I thought it won't be necessary and never attempt to use it.

Comment: @Ben, I updated the answer as I saw why the div was always pointing to the last marker.  I'm not sure that will fix the "a is undefined", though.  You need to step through your code and find where it's happening - take out as much as you can until the error goes away, then put pieces back in until you find out what's going wrong.

Comment: @ 150PoundsOfDonamite: If I call the functions `addMarker` and `addInfoName` within the `process` function, wouldn't the `var marker` declared within this function be used? Because, if I remove those newly added lines, all the markers within the array do appear.

Comment: I have even tried replacing the `listDisplay.onmouseover` with an inline mouseover on the DIV, but that didn't work as well. :(

Comment: No, `var marker` will not get defined here because the functions `addMarker` and `addInfoName` are defined outside of `process`'s context.  In your example, the "higher" context for those 2 functions is the global scope.  It would, however, work the way you expect if you moved those function definitions inside `process`. Remember, scope is not created by calling a function, it is created by defining a function.

Comment: @ 150PoundsOfDonamite: I mean, all the markers do appear if I keep the two functions outside and declare the `var marker` inside the `process` function. According to your argument, then a "marker is undefined" error would have appeared, but it didn't.

Comment: I didn't say the marker isn't getting defined.  I said that the marker inside of process is never getting defined.  In both addMarker and addInfoName it is accessing a global variable marker.  Each time you call addMarker, it is overwriting the last marker created.

Comment: @ 150PoundsOfDonamite: I read what bobince wrote and get what you mean now. Thanks! I am trying to see whether his solution will work.