# Appending HTML Content with Attributes to a jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery

I want to add DIV tags with attributes within a selected element. I understand that the normal way of inserting HTML content according to the [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is to:

```
$('#selected_element').append('<DIV id=' + A + '>{HTML CONTENT}</DIV>');
```

However, I also need to add mouse events on the DIV tags at the same time. I note that there is a way that looks like this:

```
$('#selected_element').append($('<DIV>', {
 mouseover: function(){alert('mouseover');},
 mouseout: function(){alert('mouseout');}
}));
```

**How do I combine the two methods to add both content and attributes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $div = $('<div>{content}</div>').attr('attrName', 'attrVal').hover(
  function() {
    alert('mouseover');
  },
  function() {
    alert('mouseout');
  }
);

$('#selected_element').append($div);
```

Comment: How does `.hover` knows whether it is a mouseover or mouseout so that it will issue the corresponding alerts?

Comment: It doesn't 'know,' but the first function fires on `mouseenter` the second on `mouseleave` (by design, and according to the [API reference for `hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: The first function passed to `hover()` is the callback for a `mouseover` event, the second function passed is the callback for a `mouseout` event. [Documentation for `hover()` is here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)